# How to split/divide/break torrent file?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, p2p, rtorrent, peer-to-peer

Is there any way to split/divide/break a torrent file into many parts and then download parts with my friends and combine all parts into a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.torrent` [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file) is binary encoded, so you can't just parse out text from it. You would need to edit the file using a program to do it on your behalf (or I suppose you could edit the binary data by hand with a hex editor...).

The .torrent [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file#File_structure) would allow you to divvy up the data you want to download, but only on a file boundary (eg you could not break 1 file up over multiple torrents). This is because the [hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_list) the torrent contains are computed from the the entirety of each files you are downloading. The .torrent file does not have the information necessary to generate hashes on just parts of the files to be downloaded (you could not compute the hash until you had already downloaded it). Additionally, Torrent clients do not have a means of joining together partial files on disk so you would have to find a way to cat the parts together.

You can remove or include files from the download, but that's really the extent of your capabilities, even if you decode, hack the torrent file, and either regenerate or [re-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) the file.

If you were to write your own custom client, you could expose more functionality, but this is a completely non-trivial task.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are asking about splitting the (usually large) file that a `.torrent` file describes.

- If your purpose is downloading the file from a single seeder in a shorter period of time, then [BitTorrent protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent#Description) already does it for you. It uses [segmented file transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_file_transfer) and if you and your friend connect at the same time, your clients will download different parts of the file and then automatically share them between you.

  If you and your friend were using different links and still had a good transfer speed between your clients, you would in effect download the file collectively (more or less half/half) from a seeder.
- If your purpose is to split the data transfer size, then you could only manually disable parts of the collection (if these were multiple files) as [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1057790/493903) describes.